# How to delete an HTML element which is not appended in the DOM

Tags: javascript, html

I have created an HTML element dynamically and set the `innerHTML` value:

```js
var value = "<img src="fail" onerror="alert();" />";
    this.wrapElement = document.createElement('div');
    this.wrapElement.innerHTML = value;
```

After that I removed some unwanted attributes then return the `innerHTML`. Here is the relevant code:

```js
    SanitizeHtmlHelper.sanitize = function (value) {
        var item = this.beforeSanitize();
        var output = this.serializeValue(item, value);
        return output;
    };
    SanitizeHtmlHelper.serializeValue = function (item, value) {
        this.removeAttrs = item.selectors.attributes;
        this.removeTags = item.selectors.tags;
        this.wrapElement = document.createElement('div');
        this.wrapElement.innerHTML = value;
        this.removeXssTags();
        this.removeJsEvents();
        this.removeXssAttrs();
        return this.wrapElement.innerHTML;
    };
```

When I set the returned value to document innerText property, it throws an error:

Sample - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ufhmyk?file=index.ts

### Repo steps

- Open sample
- See network tab

While set returned value to `innerHtml` property it must validate tag but while set `innerText`, it doesn't have to validate tag but now but validates.

Because I haven't delete the created element, is there any way to overcome my issue?

> Note: already tried to set `this.wrapElement.innerHTML=''` but no luck

Comment: Please put your runnable example **here, on-site**, not just offsite. [Here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/). (You've used the right tool, you just haven't filled everything in.) The point is that all of the code, etc., needed to answer your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Right now, I have no idea what the error you're running into is, or what the code for most of your methods is. See also: [mcve]

Comment: The answer to *"How to delete html element which is not append in DOM"* is: You don't. You just release your reference to it. But that seems unlikely to be your real question.

Comment: HI @T.J.Crowder,  I have already provided sample - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ufhmyk?file=index.ts