# How to restrict html tag attribute validation?

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild, removechild

Hi have create html element like below:

```js
var element = document.createElement('div');
element.innerHTML = `<img src="fail" onerror="alert();" />`;
element.setAttribute('id', 'check');
document.body.append(element);

// removed element from DOM
 element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

When you run this code, you will see console error like below:

> GET https://stacksnippets.net/fail 404 (Not Found)

**Is there any sugestion to resolve this console error?**

Comment: yes, provide a valid image url. you are trying to load a image from https://stacksnippets.net/fail which doesn't exist (404), so browser is printing that error for you. provide a valid src attribute to image tag.

Comment: Thats my case, that innerhtml will defer. i am just create new element and sanitize html string then send to another method. refer below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61591222/how-to-delete-an-html-element-which-is-not-appended-in-the-dom?noredirect=1#comment108947764_61591222

Comment: You can not prevent 404 error unless you use a valid image url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried lke below and resolve my pblm

```js
 private static removeElement(): void {
         // Removes an element's attibute to avoid html tag validation
         let nodes: HTMLCollection = this.wrapElement.children;
         for (let j: number = 0; j < nodes.length; j++) {
             let attribute: NamedNodeMap = nodes[j].attributes;
             for (let i: number = 0; i < attribute.length; i++) {
                 this.wrapElement.children[j].removeAttribute(attribute[i].localName);
             }
         }
    }
```